# WildFly 12: error jboss.remoting.management.channel.registry

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am upgrading application from wildFly 8 to wildFly 12. Checked the standalone-full.xml in both the versions, looks good. The server starts, but the deployment of the ear fails with error.

> 2018-05-29 14:44:34,674 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>   ("core-service" => "management"), ("management-interface" =>
>   "http-interface") ]) - failure description: { "WFLYCTL0412: Required
>   services that are not installed:" =>
>   ["jboss.remoting.management.channel.registry"], "WFLYCTL0180: Services
>   with missing/unavailable dependencies" =>
>   ["org.wildfly.management.http.extensible.shutdown is missing
>   [jboss.remoting.management.channel.registry]"] }
>   2018-05-29 14:44:34,685 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] 
>   (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address:
>   ([("deployment" => "wfa-0.5.ear")]) - failure description: {
>   "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [

=================================
Structure of ear:

> +- lib
>   +- META-INF
>   |  +- application.xml
>   |  +- jboss-deployment-structure.xml
>   |  +- MANIFEST.MF
>   +- cache-0.5.jar
>   +- command-0.5.jar
>   +- common-0.5.jar
>   +- dar-0.5.jar
>   +- finders-0.5.jar
>   +- job-management-0.5.jar
>   +- rest-facade-0.5.war
>   +- server-facade-0.5.jar
>   +- upgrade-portal-0.5.war
>   +- upgraders-0.5.jar
>   +- user-management-0.5.jar
>   +- web-services-0.5.war
>   +- z_asup-0.5.jar

===================

Comment: are you using IPv6 instead of IPv4? You can check this by verifying the value of java.net.preferIPv4Stack property. It should be true.

Comment: My google fu is failing as well - it does appear to be an issue with the http-interface or jboss-remoting.  My only suggestion if you dont figure it out yourself would be to check the [JBoss Developer Forums](https://developer.jboss.org/places) and post your problem there, if it gets figured out be sure to answer your question here for others that might run into similar issues.  Good luck!

Comment: This log line just is not enough to answer your question, please enter more details.

Comment: can you post contents of your standalone-full*.xml or domain*.xml config file?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3014791 you should use `<http-upgrade enabled="true" .../>` in `<http-interface .../>`. In my case (WildFly 25), it was:

```xml
    <management-interfaces>
      <http-interface http-authentication-factory="management-http-authentication">
        <http-upgrade enabled="true" sasl-authentication-factory="management-sasl-authentication"/>
        <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
      </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
```

And I used the referenced `management-http-authentication` and `management-sasl-authentication` defaults from default configuration of Elytron subsystem.